# Why ReactiveMongoTemplate save does not work with Testcontainers

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, testcontainers

I have a spring-boot application.
I have entity:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(COLLECTION_NAME)
public class PersonEntity {

    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "person_info";
    private static final String PERSON_NAME = "person_name";


    @Id
    private PersonId id;

    @Field(name = PERSON_NAME)
    private String personName;

    
    @Indexed(name = "ttl_index", expireAfterSeconds=20)
    private LocalDateTime date;
}
```

I have a repository interface:

```
public interface PersonRepository {

    void saveWithTtl(PersonEntity entity);
}
```

The repository implementation:

```
@Slf4j
@Repository
public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository {

    private final int expireAfterSeconds;
    private final ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public PersonRepositoryImpl(@Value("${ttl.index}") int expireAfterSeconds,
                                                  ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.expireAfterSeconds = expireAfterSeconds;
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveWithTtl(PersonEntity entity) {
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(PersonEntity.class)
                .ensureIndex(new Index().on(PersonEntity.CREATED_AT, ASC)
                        .expire(expireAfterSeconds)).subscribe(result -> log.info("Ttl index has been created: {}", result));
        mongoTemplate.save(entity).subscribe(result -> log.info("Entity has been saved: {}", result));
    }
}
```

And, finally, I have test that does not work:

```
@DataMongoTest
@Testcontainers
public class PersonRepositoryIT {
    @Autowired
    private ReactiveMongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository repository;

    @Container
    private static MongoDbContainer mongoDbContainer = new MongoDbContainer();


    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() {
        repository.deleteAll();
    }


    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void registerMongoProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", mongoDbContainer::getReplicaSetUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldCreateAndDeleteRecordsAfterDelay_whenSaveWithTtl_givenDefinedTll() {
        //given
        PersonEntity givenEntity =  PersonEntity.builder().createdAt(LocalDateTime.now())
                .personName("Joe")
                .id(PERSON_ID).build();
        //when
        repository.saveWithTtl(givenEntity);

        //then
        StepVerifier.create(mongoTemplate.estimatedCount(PersonEntity.COLLECTION_NAME))
                .expectNext(1L)
                .verifyComplete();

    }
}
```

On **expectNext** it fails coz it returns 0 and not 1.
mongoTemplate.estimatedCount returns 0

When I test the repository from Postman (repo is calling inside service), it creates the document in MongoDB wil ttl index, as expected.

In test fonfig I have set the ${ttl.index} to 20.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Anni :-). I'm willing to have a look at this, but it would make my life easier if you have an example repository. Any chance this is on Github somewhere?

Comment: Does this test work fine if you are connecting it to a MongoDB instance you started manually?

Comment: I tried to replicate the code provided and the only different thing I did is adding `DataMongoTest(includeFilters = @Filter(Repository.class))`. Would be great if can share a repository with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is to late, but I had the same problem today.
I Found your question looking for an answer for my problem hahahaha.

This snipped worked for me:

```
@Container
public static MongoDBContainer container = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:6"));

@DynamicPropertySource
static void mongoDbProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add("spring.data.mongodb.uri", container::getReplicaSetUrl);
}

@Bean
public ReactiveMongoTemplate reactiveMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    container.start();
    ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(container.getReplicaSetUrl());
    MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
            .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
            .build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);

    return new ReactiveMongoTemplate(mongoClient,"test");
}
```

Apparently ReactiveMongoTemplate is not being injected by default, then I created my own Bean an it worked